# ROS Stacks in home and file system

Tags: ros, overlay, roboearth, roswtf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I have a ROS  in my home contain RoboEarth and its dependencies and Main ROS [fuerte in Ubuntu 12.04] in file system, I need some stacks from which in my file system so I have to link between all ..
so I use overlay to create my work space and its already in home [fuerte_workspace] how to add RoboEarth and all stacks downloaded with it as once not to add one by one as it does not work

---

---

2- that is what I have when try to add ccny_vision
I not add and also ROS in file system still missing
any solution
Thanks in Advance

```
    amal@amal-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$ cd ~/fuerte_workspace
    amal@amal-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~/fuerte_workspace$ rosws info
    WARNING [vcstools] Command failed: 'hg paths default'
     run at: '/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot'
     errcode: 1:
    Not trusting file /home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/hgrc from untrusted user root, group root
    Not trusting file /home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/hgrc from untrusted user root, group root
    not found!
    [/vcstools]
    workspace: /home/amal/fuerte_workspace
    ROS_ROOT: /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
    
     Localname                 S SCM  Version-Spec UID  (Spec)  URI  (Spec) [http(s)://...]
     ---------                 - ---- ------------ -----------  ---------------------------
   ccny_vision               x git                         robotics.ccny.cuny.edu/git/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_vision.git
     ros                       x                               
     turtlebot                 V hg   default      e47d5a1dca1c     (kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot)
     roboearth                   svn  tags/latest  -r2111       ipvs.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/roboearth/repos/public/
     knowrob                     svn  tags/latest  -r948        code.in.tum.de/pubsvn/knowrob/
     sandbox                                                    
     /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks                                     
     /opt/ros/fuerte/share                                      
     /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
```

---

3-
Now I set up RoboEarth from this

```
rosinstall ~/fuerte_workspace /opt/ros/fuerte 'http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=roboearth.rosinstall'
```

so it is in fuerte_workspace and also on home since previous set up.

I have this when run `rosmake roboearth` , so why does not go in directory of fuerte_workspace ?!

```
amal@amal-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$ cd ~/fuerte_workspace
amal@amal-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~/fuerte_workspace$ rosmake roboearth
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['roboearth']                               
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/amal/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121112-210325
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['roboearth'] to:
[]                                  
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['roboearth']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.
```

---

4- also I have this when try to know the error.

```
amal@amal-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~/fuerte_workspace$ roswtf
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

Found 1 error(s).

ERROR Not all paths in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH [/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/home/ros] point to an existing directory: 
 * /home/ros
```

---

5- this is my `rosws info`

```
amal@amal-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$ cd ~/fuerte_workspace
amal@amal-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~/fuerte_workspace$ rosws info
workspace: /home/amal/fuerte_workspace
ROS_ROOT: /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros

 Localname                  S SCM  Version-Spec UID  (Spec)  URI  (Spec) [http(s)://...]
 ---------                  - ---- ------------ -----------  ---------------------------
 stacks/knowrob               svn  tags/latest  -r966        code.in.tum.de/pubsvn/knowrob/
 pkgs/tum-ros-pkg/knowledge   svn               -r1010       tum-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/tum-ros-pkg/knowledge
 stacks/ccny_vision           git  master       e03c2bf654d5 robotics.ccny.cuny.edu/git/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_vision.git
 stacks/roboearth             svn  tags/latest  -r2111       ipvs.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/roboearth/repos/public/
 /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks                                      
 /opt/ros/fuerte/share                                       
 /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
```

---

---

(((6)))- now I have fuerte ros in file system linked with ros in home [in home contain only RoboEarth, KnowRob, ccny_vision and pkgs].
and it is clear in bash file that they are linked, so can I make home/amal/ros to be my work space ?!  and create a sandbox in it ?!

```
fi
source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java export JAVA_HOME PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin export PATH
 export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/home/amal/ros
```

---

(((7))) Sry for long inconvenience,
I try to remove it  using

```
rm -rf ~/fuerte_workspace
```

That is a pic of how it looks like [http://i.imgur.com/BH1Z6.png](https://i.imgur.com/BH1Z6.png)
and this is a part of my terminal

```
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/turtlebot__driver/rosdoc.yaml.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/turtlebot__driver/manifest.xml.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/_makefile.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/turtle__drive/_makefile.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/turtle__drive/src/turtle__drive/____init____.py.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/turtle__drive/_c_make_lists.txt.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/turtle__drive/action/_turn.action.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/turtle__drive/manifest.xml.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/stack.xml.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/_c_make_lists.txt.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/rosdep.yaml.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/~2ehgtags.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/turtlebot__urdf/mainpage.dox.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/turtlebot__urdf/_makefile.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/turtlebot__urdf/_c_make_lists.txt.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/turtlebot__urdf/meshes/_turtlebot___plate__1___logo__color.png.d': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/turtlebot__urdf/meshes/68-02421-8000-_r_a___turtlebot___f-_f___standoff.dae.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/turtlebot__urdf/meshes/plate__1__logo.dae.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/turtlebot__urdf/meshes/plate__1__logo__color.tga.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/turtlebot__urdf/meshes/68-04545__i_robot___create._s_t_l.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/turtlebot__urdf/meshes/_turtlebot___plate__1___logo__color.png.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/turtlebot__urdf/meshes/_turtlebot___plate__2___logo__color.png.d': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/turtlebot__urdf/meshes/create__body.dae.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/turtlebot__urdf/meshes/68-04545__i_robot___create.dae.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/turtlebot__urdf/meshes/plate__2__logo.dae.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/turtlebot__urdf/meshes/plate__0__logo.dae.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/turtlebot__urdf/meshes/_turtlebot___plate__2___logo.dae.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/turtlebot__urdf/meshes/68-02421-8000-_r_a___turtlebot___f-_f___standoff__color.png.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/turtlebot__urdf/meshes/68-04552-2000-_r_a___turtlebot___m-_f___standoff__color.png.i': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/home/amal/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot/.hg/store/data/turtlebot__urdf/meshes/_turtlebot___plate__0___logo.dae.i': Permission denied
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47765/ros-stacks-in-home-and-file-system/) by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2012-11-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2012-11-07**:
yes, it is normal. Binaries are dowloaded to /opt/ros/fuerte by default. You don't need to link, just try building the stack you downloaded.

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-11-07**:
what do you mean by "try building the stack you downloaded." ?!

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-11-08**:
@dornhege
after I have fuerte_workspace in home I have to add stacks that I wish in it !!

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-08**:
yes.

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-11-08**:
@dornhege
I have this error when try add ccny_vision
ERROR: Error processing 'ccny_vision' : [ccny_vision] Checkout of http://robotics.ccny.cuny.edu/git/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_vision.git version None into /home/amal/fuerte_workspace/ccny_vision failed.
I do not understand check this link for what ?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-08**:
How did you add the ccny_vision repository to your workspace? rosws set --git http://robotics.ccny.cuny.edu/git/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_vision.git is the right command. What's the content of `~/fuerte_workspace/.rosinstall`?

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-11-08**:
I add to ~/fuerte_workspace/.rosinstall  [RoboEarth and KnowRob] and I  then want to add also ccny_vision to fuerte_workspace but get error!! . I already have it automatic when download RoboEarth but in home/ros/stacks.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-08**:
Did you use the command @Lorenz posted? That is the correct one. If there is an error, update your post by copying that error there and list your .rosinstall.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-08**:
Can you try `rosws set ccny_vision --git hXttp://robotics.ccny.cuny.edu/git/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_vision.git` (remove X from hXttp)

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-11-08**:
rosws: error: Element {'git': {'local-name': 'ccny_vision', 'uri': 'http://robotics.ccny.cuny.edu/git/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_vision.git'}} already exists, did you mean --detached ?
already exist ?!

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-08**:
If it exists like that, you shouldn't be getting that error. Please remove all lines for this package from .rosinstall and redo the `rosws set`. Then execute `rosws regenerate` and `source setup.bash`. If it doesn't work, post your .rosinstall.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-08**:
Does it work now? If not post your complete .rosinstall file and the output of rosws info.

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-11-11**:
@dornhege please check last update

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-11-11**:
@moritz @dornhege  Thanks :)

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-11-20**:
all please see my update (((6)))

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-20**:
The manually defined ROS_PACKAGE_PATH should not set /opt/ros/fuerte... entries, but rather extend the current ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. When you use rosws this is done automatically and thus it is recommended.  And yes, sure you can use ~/ros, just do exactly the same using ~/ros instead of ~/fuerte_worksp

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-11-21**:
but I have 3 work space in my home :D , so I try to remove any but it seem that it remove the entries not the hole folders. how ti remove it at all
Tanks :)

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-11-21**:
I want to delete fuerte_workspace [http://i.imgur.com/HkaEj.png](https://i.imgur.com/HkaEj.png)
and That is ros which I want to be my workspace [http://i.imgur.com/Dyv61.png](https://i.imgur.com/Dyv61.png)
I mean it is already exist and linked to ros in file system but I want to make it an overlay so can edit not just a user . I need clarification please.thanks

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-21**:
I don't really understand what you mean/want. You can create a new ros workspace from any folder and add things to it via rosws. To enable a specific one for using it, just source it's setup.bash. Likewise removing any workspace is just removing that folder.

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-11-22**:
Ok thanks I will try it

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-22**:
If you get permission denied errors, something with the permissions is wrong. What do you get for `ls -l` with the files that error? Did you check that out as another user?

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-11-23**:
that is what I have when try  "ls -l"
drwxrwxr-x  5 amal amal   4096 Nov 22 20:53 fuerte_workspace

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-23**:
This is the directory. The errors you get are from other files.

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-11-23**:
I am really sorry for long inconvenience, I am not understand what you want to say ?!
simply I want to remove the work space, but It does not want to be removed I do not know why? . can I skip this and create another one, mean not to asign a path to this that doesnot want to be removed
?!!

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-23**:
As long as you don't source the setup.bash of a ROS workspace it won't be active and doesn't interfere with anything else.

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-11-23**:
oh thanks, it will be good solution
I Really appreciate your patience :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should create an [overlay](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays) with rosws that adds the downloaded stack to your ROS workspace.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a rosinstall file for RoboEarth that you can use by following the instructions at http://ros.org/wiki/roboearth#Installation

In your case, you need to replace ~/ros with the path of your local overlay, e.g. ~/fuerte_workspace

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2012-11-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2